# How to create a checkbox preferences area in your app using Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator and I've been trying to figure out how i can create a section within my app, where users can store there setting by checking a number of checkboxes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for iphone or android?

```
/* store sections in here */
var mySections = []; 

/* create section */
var mySection[0] = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection({
  headerTitle:"first section"
})

/* tableview row to store checkbox */
var tableviewrow0 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();

/* if you don't want to build your own UI element you need 
 * to use the provided elements. checkboxes aren't standard 
 * ui elements, so you need to use switcher 
 */
var switcher0 = Ti.UI.createSwitcher({
  value: true, // or false
  right: 10 // place it onto right side
});
tableviewrow0.add(switcher0);

/* label */
var label0 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  value:"option one",
  textAlign:"left",
  left:10
});
tableviewrow0.add(label0);

/* add row to section*/
mySection[0].add(tableviewrow0);

/* tableview */
var tbv = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  data:mySection
});
win.add(tbv);
```

you need to continue for the next rows and sections. i didn't compiled it so be careful; it's just an idea. for android there are special preferences; look in the [kitchensink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/preferences.js).

Comment: you're right there are special preferences for android. I built a preferences.xml under my res folder. The problem was i couldn't find a way to check whether the state of the checkboxes where checked or unchecked.

Comment: you need to check the checkbox.value value. the best way is to react at the change event. checked means checkbox.value=true.

Comment: you mean i have to check the android:key="checkbox" /> ?

Comment: yes, like here: https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/platform/android/res/xml/preferences.xml

Comment: that part i understand but how do you read this from your app.js file?